# Kendo UI - How do I bind data from an array of strings to a grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, asp.net-web-api

I have been unsuccessful at getting data to show in a Kendo grid based on a web api action I have created.

In the code below I am reading data from a web api action at /api/controller/action.  The data is seen in the browser as the response below which is a list of strings returned from the action method.

Response from Server:

```xml
<string>Value 1</string>
```

Init function within cshtml:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
                    var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: "/api/controller/action"
                            },
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: false,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "string",
                                title: "Name",
                                width: "100%"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
```

How do I get data to map to the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that looks like XML. Be sure in your API to use the KendoMVC DataSourceRequest Object to return data in the right Json format.

Here is an example:

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var result = ReadData();
        return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

FYI the Json of

```
 <string>Value 1</string>
```

Should be like this

```
{"string":"Value 1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like you are returning JSON from your controller action and your datasource is set to accept json.

Comment: Would I need xml on this instead?  I am trying to make a simple example to produce data.